# handsontable load data with ajax on site load

Tags: jquery, ajax, handsontable

can someone explain why this code works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var container = document.getElementById('example');


    function getData() {

        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'someurl',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(res) {
                result = res.data;
            }
        });

        return result;

    }

    var hot = new Handsontable(container,{
        data:getData(),
        startRows: 8,
        startCols: 8,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,

        stretchH: 'all',
        minSpareRows: 0,
        contextMenu: true

    });

});
```

and if i change async to true it doesn´t work.

The working code comes with this message in the console:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

And the important question what I have to change that handsontable will work with async:true.

Thanks a lot. I have searched google and only find examples with a load Button not with loading on site load.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you use `async:true`, the handsontable instance will be instanciate with no data because getData() return null.

Maybe you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('example');

    var hot = new Handsontable(container,{
        startRows: 8,
        startCols: 8,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        stretchH: 'all',
        minSpareRows: 0,
        contextMenu: true
    });

    function loadData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'someurl',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function(res) {
                hot.loadData(res.data);
            }
        });
    }

    loadData();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by Joakim works but also fires 2 ajax calls on the same url after DOM is loaded. (which can be annoying when ajax request returns a big set of data). Javascript Promise can help solving the async issue like this :

```
function handsonTableLoad(url) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', url);
      request.responseType = 'json';
      request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          resolve(request.response);
        } else {
          reject(Error('Data didn\'t load successfully; error code:' + request.statusText));
        }
      };
      request.onerror = function() {
          reject(Error('There was a network error.'));
      };
      request.send();
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
      var container = document.getElementById('example');

      handsonTableLoad(someurl).then(function(response) {
        var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: response,
                startRows: 8,
                startCols: 8,
                rowHeaders: true,
                colHeaders: true       
          });
      }, function(Error) {
        console.log(Error);
      });
    });
```